# Accessing remote Umbraco website from Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco

I'm about to deploy a site where some functionality is omitted to get the website launched as soon as possible. This means that after the site has been deployed to a live server, some development still needs be done.

I have mainly been used to working on local projects, and have just been playing around with opening the site as a FTP project in VS2012.

This seems to be the way to go, but unfortunately, IntelliSense doesnn't play nice (not all namespaces are recognized) and when re-building the project, it seems as the whole Umbraco project is recompiled (which creates an enormous overhead). And I have not found a way of excluding Umbraco specific folders from the project.

Another thing is that the project is recognized as a WebForms project and not MVC4, for which I would also like a fix :)

Any suggestions on how to carry on from here? Suggestions and best practices is very welcome!

Comment: Are you using the Umbraco source or are you using the pre-compiled Umbraco distribution?

Comment: I'm using the pre-compiled distribution.

Comment: Edit. Umbraco is actually installed from a NuGet package into an empty MVC4 application.